# setOnKeyListener parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm new at kotline in Android Studio, I don't understand how some code samples have parameters like:

```
username_edit_text.setOnKeyListener({_,_,_, ->

    })
```

how is it possible?, I mean, when I use java I can't name parameters like the example ( **_** ), i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_ can be named for unused parameters, for example you have callback function with 3 parameters, but you need only one of them, so for shorter code you can name parameters you don't need as _

Comment: Thank you! i can't believe it... i said it and i will say it again, kotlin is a very good programming language